# Querying navigational properties in BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, breeze

When querying for entities from server with Breeze, and including navigational properties, all of them are included and sent over the wire. Is there a way to return only some navigational properties, using only client side code?

Lets say we have Customers and their Orders. We can easily filter Customers by their orders, using something like this:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Customers')
                .where('orders', 'any', 'price', '>', 1000)
                .expand('orders');

return manager.executeQuery(query);
```

This returns all Customers that have an Order with price over 1000, and includes their Orders in the entity. But it transfers ALL of their Orders.

Is there a way to include only SOME Orders, e.g. those that cost more than 1000, using only client side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, this is simply not a capability that the OData syntax, ( what breeze is converting your query to under the covers) supports.

That said, you could invert the query. i.e.

```
 var query = entityQuery.from('Orders')
            .where('price', '>', 1000)
            .expand('customer');
```

This will result in exactly the entities you want in the EntityManager cache.

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. The only problem is that the resolver would hook up all cached Orders to the Customers from the inverted query. Which is not a big problem, just requires some logistics. Thanks for clarifying :)